# uitableview footer

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have added a footer to the `UITableView` in plain style if the user clicks the textfield of last cell the tableview is not scrolling

```
    -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:   (NSInteger)section{


            UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
            [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            return view;
}
```

if it is a sectioned table this works, please help

Comment: what you exact want? and which problem you face??

Comment: i just want to scroll the tableview if the textfield in the tableviewcell is hidden by keyboard hence i added the footer for the tableview, this functionality works if it is a sectioned tableview for plain tableview it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField == yourTextField){ /// here write name of your Textfield in which you want to scroll tableview
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        yourTableView.frame = CGRectMake(yourTableView.frame.origin.x, -160, yourTableView.frame.size.width, tblContactUS.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
     }
     return YES;
}
```

and put your TableView with previous frame then use bellow method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if(textField == yourTextField){ /// here write name of your Textfield in which you want to scroll down tableview
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
            yourTableView.frame = CGRectMake(yourTableView.frame.origin.x, 0, yourTableView.frame.size.width, tblContactUS.frame.size.height);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
     }
    return YES;
}
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: thanks this works and solved my problem but i dnt knw why adding a footer in uitableview for plain styled doesnt scroll top i also added the below code [self.detailTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.detailTableView indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]; but still not working

Comment: @lochana i am not sure mate but its problem with group of section in which its move to first section of Table when its in Group style and in simple here this method not find the sections in table because its style is plain so i think this reson for this problem...

Comment: thank you and i will stick with your answer for plain tableview